# Как сделать проверку на диагональ экрана?

Tags: java, android

Помогите сделать проверку на диагональ экрана? Например: когда экран маленький, то делается одно действие, а когда большой, то другое?

Comment: надеюсь ответить на ваш вопрос [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155559/how-to-get-android-device-screen-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказал David.

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width=dm.widthPixels;
int height=dm.heightPixels;
int dens=dm.densityDpi;
double wi=(double)width/(double)dens;
double hi=(double)height/(double)dens;
double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

`double screenInches` это и будет диагональ. А вообщем формула диагонали D=sqrt(a^2+b^2), не зная алгебры и геометрии очень трудно программировать

Comment: Спасибо......я просто про то, что допустим у меня много спиннеров + много едит текстов+ кнопка и все это на большой экран помещается, а на маленький нет.... вот и хочу сделать что когда на большом экране делаешь рассчет все было как было, а на маленьком как нить в виде алерт диалога что ли....

Comment: Если вы в студии делаете, то там есть папки такие как drawable-mdpi hdpi и т.д., туда вам нужно закидывать картинки